# Dynamic string concatenation with strcat in C

Tags: c, string-concatenation, strcat

I have experienced an issue while using strcat, using realloc however, strcat overwrites destination string

```
char *splitStr(char *line) {
        char *str_;
        str_ = (char *) malloc(1);
        char *ptr = strtok(line,"\n");
        int a;
        while (ptr != NULL) {
              if (ptr[0] != '$') {
                        printf("oncesi %s\n", str_);
                        a = strlen(ptr) + strlen(str_) + 1;
                        str_ = realloc(str_, a);
                        strcat(str_, ptr);
                        str_[a] = '\0';
                        printf("sontasi:%s\n", str_);
              }
              ptr = strtok(NULL, "\n");
        }
        printf("splitStr %d\n", strlen(str_));
        printf("%s", str_);
        return str_;
}
```

and my input value is ;

```
*4
$3
200
$4
4814
$7
SUCCESS
$4
3204
```

so I want to split this input value via strtok;
strtok(line,'\n');

and concat all line without start "$" char to new char. However, this code give following output;

```
line: *4
oncesi 
sontasi:*4
oncesi *4
200tasi:*4
200esi *4
4814asi:*4
4814si *4
SUCCESS:*4
SUCCESS*4
3204ESS:*4
splitStr 25
```

seems to overwrite source string.
do you have any idea why this issue could be happening ?

Comment: looks like you've got some `\r` in your file

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Undefined behavior... `str_` is used when the memory it points to is uninitialized

Comment: Undefined behavior... `str_[a]='\0';` writes outside allocated memory

Comment: `str_[a] = '\0';` is incorrect since it overruns allocated memory. It should have been `str_[a-1] = '\0';` (but that is unnecessary because `strcat` deals with it). The string `str_` is supposed to point is not initialized and invokes undefined behaviour when the program flow enters the `if`block at first time. It must be initialized like `str_[0] = '\0';` just after the `malloc`.

Comment: You also forgot to initialize str_ after the first malloc. This way the  first *strlen(str_)* will be bogus. you need `str_[0] = 0;` immediately after malloc.

Comment: As pointed out by @ChrisTurner, it is very likely that your lines end with "\r\n", causing the position of the cursor to move to the first position on the same line when printing out on the terminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the indicated functionality
3. is slightly reformated for readability of output
4. checks for errors from `malloc()` and `realloc()`
5. shows how to initialize the str[] array, which is the problem in the OPs posted code.
6. the function: `strlen()` returns a `size_t`, not an `int`.  so the proper output format conversion specifier is: `%zu`
7. does not use trailing underscores on variable names

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


char *splitStr( char *line ) 
{
    printf("original line: %s\n", line);

    char *str = malloc(1);
    if( !str )
    {
        perror( "malloc failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    str[0] = '\0';   // critical statement
    char *token = strtok(line,"\n");


    while( token ) 
    {
        if( token[0] != '$') 
        {
            char* temp = realloc( str, strlen( token ) + strlen( str ) + 1 );
            if( ! temp )
            {
                perror( "realloc failed" );
                free( str );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            str = temp;   // update pointer

            strcat(str, token);
            printf( "concat result: %s\n", str );
        }
        token = strtok(NULL, "\n");
    }

    printf("splitStr %zu\n", strlen(str));
    return str;
}


int main( void )
{
    char  firstStr[] = "$abcd\n$defg\nhijk\n";
    char *firstNewStr = splitStr( firstStr );
    printf( "returned: %s\n\n\n\n", firstNewStr );
    free( firstNewStr );

    char  secondStr[] = "abcd\ndefg\nhijk\n";
    char *secondNewStr = splitStr( secondStr );
    printf( "returned: %s\n\n\n\n", secondNewStr );
    free( secondNewStr );
}
```

a run of the proposed code results in:

```
original line: $abcd
$defg
hijk

concat result: hijk
splitStr 4
returned: hijk



original line: abcd
defg
hijk

concat result: abcd
concat result: abcddefg
concat result: abcddefghijk
splitStr 12
returned: abcddefghijk
```

Comment: This does *not* answer OP's question. However, no down-vote due to better code. (Even your spacing is inconsistent.)

Comment: @thebusybee,  This statement: `str[0] = '\0';   // critical statement` is missing from the OPs posted code.  I thought I made that clear when I placed the comment: `// critical statement`  Also,  `main()` calls `splitStr()` with two slightly different strings due to the `if( token[0] != '$')` statement in the OPs version of the `splitStr()` function, so as to highlight both conditions of that statement

Answer (score 1):

Your input contains Windows/DOS end-of-line codings `"\r\n"`.

Since `strtok()` just replaces `'\n'` with `'\0'`, the `'\r'` stays in the string. On output it moves the cursor to the left and additional characters overwrite old characters, at least visually.

Your concatenated string should be OK, however. Count the characters, and don't forget to include a `'\r'` for each line: `"*4\r200\r4814\rSUCCESS\r3204\r"` are 25 characters as the output `splitStr 25` shows.

---

*Additional notes:*

- As others already said, `str_ = (char *) malloc(1);` does **not** initialize the space `str_` points to. You need to do this yourself, in example by `str_[0] = '\0';`.
- Don't use underscores that way.
- You don't need to cast the result of `malloc()`, it is a `void*` that is compatible to `char*` (and any other).